# Clip borders from raster images of all different sizes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I have hundreds of raster images from which I would like to clip out the borders (Shown In the example below, keep the highlighted portion, remove the white borders).
I have used the Clip Raster by mask layer option before which worked well when all the raster images had the same height and width. However this time all the raster images have different widths. Is it possible to somehow clip these images in bulk.

[image]

Comment: Are the margins always of the same size in pixels?

Comment: What software are you using? Also, you have an image or a graphic representation of some data and not the data itself.  If the border width of you graphic is always the same you could use ImageMagick to identify the image size and crop the  images accordingly .  See here: https://imagemagick.org/script/identify.php here: https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/  or here:  https://deparkes.co.uk/2015/04/30/batch-crop-images-with-imagemagick/

Comment: No, the margins are all different. 

I am using QGIS.

Comment: In the days of AI there must be a method for finding the four corners automatically. Search with "automatic georeferencing of scanned maps" seems to find some interesting papers.

Comment: Can you post a link to two of these different files?

Comment: Are the images georeferenced? And I assume the dark blue 'highlighted portion' is not the image itself, that is masking it?